# QR VCard in chillerlan/php-qrcode for ios name field is wrong

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code, vcf-vcard

In laravel i use chillerlan/php-qrcode to create a QR VCard.
When android scan the qr all field is populated while in ios.iphone the firstname is empty and the lastname contain all the value.

Reference for chillerlan document https://github.com/chillerlan/php-qrcode/blob/a301af5b7faa7fcd690b29f38b283616a7d93b89/docs/Appendix/URI-Content.md#L195

Working fine

`Android`

```
First name: ValueFirstname
Middle name: ValueMiddlename
Last name: ValueLastname
```

First name is empty and Last name contain all the value

`Iphone/IOS`

```
First name:
Last name: ValueFirstname ValueMiddlename ValueLastname
```

Code

```
firstname = $vcard_request->input('firstname');
         $middlename = $vcard_request->input('middlename');
         $lastname = $vcard_request->input('lastname');
        
 
 
         $vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n";
         
 
         if (!empty($middlename) && strtolower($middlename) !== 'n/a') {
            $formattedName = "$firstname $middlename $lastname";
            $vcard .= "N:$formattedName\r\n";
        } else {
            $formattedName = "$firstname $lastname";
            $vcard .= "N:$formattedName\r\n";
        }
         
     
 
         $vcard .= "VERSION:4.0\r\n";
 
      
         $vcard .= "END:VCARD";
```

composer.json

```
"chillerlan/php-qrcode": "^4.3",
```

Comment: Can you show the full interpreted vCard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android it may work well but for iOS it expects these names to be in their specific positions according to the `VCard` specification.Try this >>

$firstname = $vcard_request->input('firstname');
$middlename = $vcard_request->input('middlename');
$lastname = $vcard_request->input('lastname');

```
$vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n";

$formattedName = $lastname . ';' . $firstname . ';' . $middlename . ';;';
$vcard .= "N:" . $formattedName . "\r\n";

$vcard .= "VERSION:4.0\r\n";
$vcard .= "END:VCARD";
```